# Given a cubic polynomial $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are integers, under what conditions does the polynomial have integer roots?

Tags: polynomials

I've found a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6110) written on this, but it deals with only special cases such as $d=0$, $a+b+c+d=1$ etc. I would like to know a necessary and a sufficient condition that will determine whether a cubic equation with integer coefficients also has integer roots.

Answer (score 1):

Let the integer root be $n$. Then

$$(x-n)(ex^2+fx+g) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

for some $e,f,g$.

$$x^3(e) + x^2(f-en)+x(g-fn)-(ng) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

We have that

$$a=e,b=f-en,c=g-fn,d=ng$$

$$b=f-an,c=g-fn,d=ng$$

$$f=b+an,g=f+cn,d=ng$$

$$g=b+(a+c)n,d=ng$$

$$d=n(b+(a+c)n)$$

If there exists an integer $n$ such that

$$n^2(a+c)+bn-d=0$$

then there exists an integer $n$ such that $an^3+bn^2+cn+d=0$

We then get that, by using the quadratic formula:

$$n = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+2(a+c)d}}{2(a+c)}$$

so one of these values must be an integer.

Comment: What about the case when all roots of a cubic are integers?

Comment: Must say this is a brilliant approach!

Comment: @ShreyAryan Thanks! I just bashed it out, but I'm glad I was able to help. I'll add the case where they're all integers in a minute.

Comment: I was thinking about the Rational Root test. If $p/q$ is root of the cubic, then $p|a$ and $q|d$. But in order for the rational number to be an integer, $q=1$, which obviously divides $d$. Therefore, we only need to ensure that $p|a$. However, the real trouble comes when the cubic polynomial is monic. In that case $p=1,-1$.